# How to run a Modal popup, or javascript popup when some change in code

Tags: development

I want to execute a warning popup from a webpart when the value is out of range. pop up must be created by the code behind

Comment: HI could you clarify this for me

How to hide Asp bottom from WebPart, and click him from the cs file

Comment: I want to popup a popup window when somebody get a values more then 8/8 walue. I must run this from cs file, so i must click by something  to the button which is hidden

Comment: is there no way to do this validation on the client side with javascript